三角形を表示するプログラムについて
以下のコードで三角形を色別で描写するプログラムを作りました。
PaintTriangle関数の111行目で作成している三角形ですが、bmpファイルを見ると、こちらの三角形が2つできている感じになってしまいます。
原因がわかる方いましたら教えていただきたいです
bには三点のx,yそれぞれの最小値が入るようにしているので、
PaintTriangle(img, Nx / 2, Ny / 3, Nx / 4, 4 * Ny / 3, -Nx / 4, Ny / 2, 60);

の場合だと、Ny/3が最小値となり、for文でスキャンされていく範囲に含まれないので、画像のような部分(左下の余分な三角形）に三角形は表示されないと思うのですが、、、
また、このようなときにどのようにしてエラーを見つけていくかプロセスも簡単に教えていただけると幸いです！（できる方の思考回路？ようなもの、あるいはデバックの方法、です！）
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    "cglec.h"

int LineFunc(int x, int y, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)  //点(x,y)が正領域なら正値，
{
    return (x2 - x1) * (y - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x - x1);
}   //負領域なら負値を返す関数

int findMinimum(int a, int b, int c) {
    int min = a; // まずは最初の変数を最小値として仮定する

    // 2番目の変数と比較して、より小さい値を最小値とする
    if (b < min) {
        min = b;
    }

    // 3番目の変数と比較して、より小さい値を最小値とする
    if (c < min) {
        min = c;
    }

    return min;
}
int max_of_three(int a, int b, int c) {
    int max = a;
    if (b > max) {
        max = b;
    }
    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
    }
    return max;
}
void PaintTriangle(Image img, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int g)
{   /* この関数を作成せよ */
    int a, b, c,d;
    a = findMinimum(x1, x2, x3);//aに一番小さいxの値が入る
    b = findMinimum(y1, y2, y3);
    c = max_of_three(x1, x2, x3);
    d = max_of_three(y1, y2, y3);
       
    if (LineFunc(x3, y3, x1, y1, x2, y2) > 0) {//パターン１


        for (a; a <=c; a++) {
            if (a < 0) {
                a = 0;
            }

            else if (a >= img.Nx) {
                break;
            }
            b= findMinimum(y1, y2, y3);

            for (b; b <= d; b++) {
                if (LineFunc(a, b, x2, y2, x3, y3) > 0 && LineFunc(a, b, x1, y1, x2, y2) >0&& LineFunc(a, b, x3, y3, x1, y1) > 0) {
                    *(img.Data + a * img.Ny + b) = g;
                }
                else if (b < 0) {
                    b = 0;
                }
                else if (b >= img.Ny) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (LineFunc(x3, y3, x1, y1, x2, y2) < 0) {//パターン2
        for (a; a <= c; a++) {
            if (a < 0) {
                a = 0;
            }
            else if (a >= img.Nx) {
                break;
            }
            b = findMinimum(y1, y2, y3);
            for (b; b <= d; b++) {
                if (LineFunc(a, b, x2, y2, x3, y3) < 0 && LineFunc(a, b, x1, y1, x2, y2) < 0 && LineFunc(a, b, x3, y3, x1, y1) < 0) {
                    *(img.Data + a * img.Ny + b) = g;
                }
                else if (b >= img.Ny) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (b < 0) {
                    b = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int Nx, Ny;
    printf("画像の横方向ピクセル数は？ ");  scanf("%d", &Nx);
    printf("画像の縦方向ピクセル数は？ ");  scanf("%d", &Ny);
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * Nx * Ny);
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("メモリエラー!!");   exit(0);
    }
    Image img = { data, Nx, Ny };
    CglSetAll(img, 0);

    PaintTriangle(img, 0, 0, Nx - 1, Ny / 2, 3 * Nx / 4, Ny - 1, 255);
    PaintTriangle(img, Nx / 5, 4 * Ny / 5, Nx / 5 + Nx, 4 * Ny / 5, 2 * Nx / 3, -Ny / 5, 100);
    PaintTriangle(img, Nx / 2, Ny / 2, 3 * Nx / 4, 3 * Ny / 4, 3 * Nx / 4, Ny / 2, 180);  
    PaintTriangle(img, Nx / 2, Ny / 3, Nx / 4, 4 * Ny / 3, -Nx / 4, Ny / 2, 60);//この三角形が二つできている.パターン１
    CglSaveGrayBMP(img, "Triangles.bmp");
}



そろそろ質問内容がグラフィックス処理の細かい？具体的な？ところになってきたので、cglec.h, CglSetAll, CglSaveGrayBMPといったものが何(おそらくグラフィックス処理のライブラリと思われますが)であって仕様は何か、何処から入手できるのか等について情報があった方が良いと思われます。それらが非公開(例えば何かの学習コースを受講していないと使用出来ないとか)なのであれば、回答しようとする人が調査・検証することが出来ず、そのままでは助言・回答を得ることが難しくなるでしょう。その場合はそれらと同等なライブラリあるいは必要な関数だけを自分で作って質問に含めるか、公開されて誰でも使用できるライブラリに置き換えて質問した方が良いと思われます。

PaintRectangle関数の以下の箇所において、else if (b < 0)をif (b < 0)と変更すれば解消すると推察します。
(加えて、境界判定なので、if (LineFunc...より先に実行するように修正した方がいいかもしれません)
        for (b; b <= d; b++) {
            if (LineFunc(a, b, x2, y2, x3, y3) > 0 && LineFunc(a, b, x1, y1, x2, y2) >0&& LineFunc(a, b, x3, y3, x1, y1) > 0) {
                *(img.Data + a * img.Ny + b) = g;
            }
            else if (b < 0) {  // ここのelseを削除。加えて、最初に実行した方がいい
                b = 0;
            }
            else if (b >= img.Ny) {
                break;
            }
        }


補足。
座標(a, b)が「三角形の内側」と判定された場合、以降のif文が(else ifのため)評価されず、b >= img.Nyの状態になってもbreakが実行されません。
そのため、範囲外の三角形の一部が描画されていると推察します。
具体的には、b >= img.Nyの場合、
*(img.Data + a * img.Ny + b)

は、
*(img.Data + (a + 1) * img.Ny + (b - img.Ny)

と等価になります。すなわち、Y方向をラップして描画されることになります。
＃蛇足ですが、貼り付けている画像は左下が(0,0)の座標系と見受けました。なので上下の表現は避けています。


また、このようなときにどのようにしてエラーを見つけていくかプロセスも簡単に教えていただけると幸いです

描画する座標「(a, b)」が描画範囲「(0, 0)-(Nx, Ny)」に収まっているか確認するのが第一歩です。
その上で、収まっていなければ、収まるように修正する、収まるようにしているはずであれば、本当にそのように動作しているか確認する、という手順となると思います。

追記。
コメントにあった点について補足説明します。

どうしてこのようになるのでしょうか？ 指定した領域以外にアクセスすると、 不正アクセスとなってエラー表示がされるものだと思っていましたし、*(img.Data + (a + 1) * img.Ny + (b - img.Ny)このような式になる理由が分からなくて

具体例として、Nx=500, Ny=500とします。img.Dataのサイズは250000になります。(オフセットとして249999まで指定可能)
また、(x1,y1)=(250,166)、(x2,y2)=(125,666)、(x3,y3)=(-125,250)となります。
この時、PointTriangle内の処理中、(a,b)=(26,500)となった際、この座標は三角形の「内側」と判定されるので、img.Dataの次のオフセットに値を設定します。
26 × 500 + 500 = 13500

オフセット「13500」は「249999」以下ですので、メモリ領域の範囲内になり、アクセスエラーにはなりません。(※)
「13500」は描画領域のどこに当たるか、ですが、(27,0)になります。同じオフセット値になります。
27 × 500 + 0 = 13500

これは次のように考えることができます。
(26 + 1) × 500 + (500 - 500) = 13500

上記の計算を汎化して

(a + 1) * img.Ny + (b - img.Ny)

と表現しました。
つまり、同じオフセット値になる座標が2つあるため、意図しない座標への描画が発生しているというわけです。
(※)厳密にはこのコードでは範囲外アクセスする可能性はあります。(499,500)が三角形の内側となる場合です。(499 × 500 + 500 = 250000)

大変わかりやすいご回答ありがとうございます。！

無事目標の画像を作り上げることができました！
一つお聞きしたいのですが、
具体的には、b >= img.Nyの場合、
*(img.Data + a * img.Ny + b)
は、
*(img.Data + (a + 1) * img.Ny + (b - img.Ny)
と等価になります。すなわち、Y方向をラップして描画されることになります。
↑どうしてこのようになるのでしょうか？
指定した領域以外にアクセスすると、
不正アクセスとなってエラー表示がされるものだと思っていましたし、*(img.Data + (a + 1) * img.Ny + (b - img.Ny)このような式になる理由が分からなくて。。。

回答の補足として例を追記しました。
